# Cancel changes in a form CTRL+Q in x++ dynamics ax

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

Can I write code in x++ which have the same function as shortcut ctrl+q (cancel saving record in a datasource)? 
How to abort saving record in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following piece of code:

```
formRun.task(264);
```

or

```
#Task

formRun.task(#taskCtrlQ);
```